# Swift stdlib default implemention for Greate operation

Tags: swift, overloading, operator-keyword

```
extension Decimal: LCDecimalPrecise {
public static func == (lhs: Decimal, rhs: Decimal) -> Bool {
    return !((lhs - rhs).doubleValue > LCMetricUnit.moneyPrecise ||
           (rhs - lhs).doubleValue > LCMetricUnit.moneyPrecise)
}

public static func < (lhs: Decimal, rhs: Decimal) -> Bool {
    return (lhs - rhs).doubleValue < -LCMetricUnit.moneyPrecise
}

public static func > (lhs: Decimal, rhs: Decimal) -> Bool {
    return (lhs - rhs).doubleValue > LCMetricUnit.moneyPrecise
}
```

}

after overriding the first two methods(> operator method ignored), then calling the method of the following for example:

```
 if Decimal(string: "1") > Decimal(string: "2") {//TODO sth}
```

I think the less(<) operator will expect to be called according [the document and source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6fc4cef671947d1d2482951853f7f82854473d91/stdlib/public/core/Comparable.swift),

When debugging, it doesn't be called. So strange!!! Finally, we implement greater operation to work around this problem.

Comment: Why do we need to overloading Decimal operation comparable & equable, it does be derived from the bug:   https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7054

Comment: FYI, 2 letter prefixes are discouraged in Swift. They originate from Objective C, as a workaround for the lack of namespaces, to prevent symbol collisions between multiple libraries/projects. There's no need to do it in Swift, which namespaces all identifiers by module.

Comment: @S Shahid  thanks for your editing for title